# .NET 4.5 parallel processing and for loop

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I am trying to create a list of tasks which depend on the number of processors available.  I have a for loop which which seems to be behaving strangely.  I am aware of the concept of closures in javascript, and it seems like something similar could be happening here:

```
 var tasks = new Task[Environment.ProcessorCount]; 
 for(int x = 0; x < Environment.ProcessorCount; x ++)
 {
      tasks[x] = Task.Run(() => new Segment(SizeOfSegment, x * SizeOfSegment, listOfNumbers).generateNewList());
 }
```

What I am finding is when I break on the line in the for loop, the variable x seems to be correct, so it starts at 0 and ends at 3 (number of processors is 4).  But when I put the break point within the constructor for Segment, I am finding that x was actually 4 when stepping back in the Call Stack.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're capturing `x` within your lambda expression - but you've got a *single* `x` variable which changes values across the course of the loop, so by the time your task actually *runs*, it may well have a different value. You need to create a *copy* of the variable inside the loop, creating a new "variable instance" on each iteration. Then you can capture *that* variable safely:

```
for(int x = 0; x < Environment.ProcessorCount; x ++)
{
    int copy = x;
    tasks[x] = Task.Run(() => new Segment(SizeOfSegment,
                                          copy * SizeOfSegment,
                                          listOfNumbers).generateNewList());
}
```

(I'd also advise you to rename `generateNewList` to `GenerateNewList` to comply with .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: Thanks Jon, I'm pretty new to parallel processing, would you say the answer i just posted is good?  I just tested it and it seems to work, just wondering if there is any reason why it might not be ideal?

Comment: @Justin, note than in C# 5 `foreach` iteration variable in a nested lambda expression no longer captures in lambda expression [Visual C# Breaking Changes in Visual Studio 2012x](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh678682(v=vs.110).aspx). So you can replace your `for` loop with `foreach`, but it's look ugly in this case.